# Looking for some good CS videos

Tags: oop

I'm wondering if there are any good free videos out there of actual Computer Science courses (college) on hardware and programming...both.  Anyone know where I may find a few to review some concepts?

couldn't find jack in ITunes University, just a bunch of basically promotion junk for each university, nothing of real value or actual class recordings

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found by Googling: [Free Computer Science Video Lecture Courses](http://freescienceonline.blogspot.com/2006/06/free-computer-science-video-lecture_24.html), but some of the links are broken so you might need further Googling to get the right link.

Here are some starters:

- Berkeley 2006 Spring: [CS 61A The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details.php?seriesid=1906978270)
- MIT: [6.001 Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/)
- Berkeley 2006 Spring: [CS 61B Data Structures](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details.php?seriesid=1906978271)
- Berkeley 2006 Spring: [CS 61C Machine Structures](http://webcast.berkeley.edu/course_details.php?seriesid=1906978272)
- Stanford: [programming methodology](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111)
- Stanford: [programming paradigms](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=2d712634-2bf1-4b55-9a3a-ca9d470755ee)

I picked spring semesters because they are longer iirc. Here are some courses that are more advanced (and less dry).

- Stanford: [natural language processing](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=63480b48-8819-4efd-8412-263f1a472f5a)
- Stanford: [machine learning](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1)
- Stanford: [introduction to robotics](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=86cc8662-f6e4-43c3-a1be-b30d1d179743)

Comment: I'm checking out some of those links too.. hopefully they are captioned!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to check out the [Stanford University Youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/StanfordUniversity#p/p). There are some courses on computer science on there.

Some of them have taught me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Google, Yahoo, and O'Reilly all have great Tech Talks on YouTube and their dev blogs.

I highly recommend [Crockford on JavaScript](http://yuiblog.com/crockford). He gives a wonderful overview of the history of programming languages in the first lecture.

If you're interested in current technology I'd also highly recommend the Google [lecture series on MapReduce](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=D20C9DE1E63E1617) the [Tech Talk on CouchDB](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESDBM9-U804) as well as the [Yahoo talk on Node.js](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6k8lTrAE2g)